# Learning Viewflow and Documentation

Tags: django-viewflow

Viewflow sounds like a really useful library, but I've spent two days reading everything I can about it and still don't have a good idea of how to use it.

The current documentation seems to cover

1. The problems that viewflow is intended to solve
2. Some very basic examples
3. In-depth details of its various components.

What seems to be missing is the area between two and three. So I'm looking for something that gives a certain amount of detail and explains viewflow's overall structure while also explaining how things are being done and how one might do something differently if one wanted to.

Does anyone know of any tutorials or documentation that could help to fill this gap? Viewflow certainly sounds great but at the moment, I'm a long way from finding it usable.

Comment: Probably the thing you're missing is not about viewflow, but BPMN training. There are several available on the web and mooc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the thing I'm missing is extra documentation and/or tutorials to help me understand how viewflow works, the full range of things it can do, and how to customize it. Currently the documentation doesn't help me with that. I'd happily write some extra documentation myself but I don't understand viewflow well enough to do that yet.

Comment: Have you tried the cookbook also? https://github.com/viewflow/cookbook

Comment: Thanks for the cookbook suggestion cslotty - it was some help. Ultimately, I've spent lots of time reading through the code in order to understand it better. However, my view is still that the documentation needs improving, and the lack of good documentation will put lots of users off.